# Number of ways to arrange the boys and girls

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, solution-verification, combinations, alternative-proof

**Question:**

$300$ boys and $100$ girls were selected in JEE - 2007
from class - room programme. It was decided to take
a picture of the whole students in such a way that all
students to stand in a row, with boys standing in
decreasing order according to their height (assuming
all has distinct height) from left to right and girls
standing in increasing order according to their height
(assuming all has distinct height) from left to right.

In how may ways this can be done (The boys need
not stand together and girls need to stands together)?

**My approach:** Out of $400$ places in a row first we can choose $300$ places to arrange boys in descending order of the heights then in remaining hundred places we can arrange girls in descending order of the heights. I am getting $400 \choose 300$ am I correct.

Can you suggest  alternate methods?

Comment: Are you keeping in mind the girls need to stand together ??

Comment: @ishwarbb, it is said in the question that boys need not stand together. So, arrange boys in increasing order and you will have $301$ positions to place girls. But there are only $100$ girls and $201$ positions will be left which implies that some boys can stand together which contradicts the given statement.

Comment: @SarGe need not $\ne$ must not

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb, got it.

Comment: You are doing it as though the girls needn't stand together either, but the problem says they must.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The boys need not stand together and the girls need to stand together

There is one way of arranging boys here: in decreasing order, from left to right. Since there are 300 boys, there are 301 places in which we can place the girls. Since the order of boys and girls is fixed, we cannot permute them. Therefore, there are only $\boxed{301}$ ways of doing this.